# C++11: std::result_of<> template argument vs std::function<>

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, result-of

I did do some research on `std::result_of<>`, and am aware how it's used on a high level, but am still pretty confused on this magical thing.

So, if I understand it correctly, the form `R (Args..)` should be interpreted by the compiler as a function type taking the arguments of types `Args...` and returning type `R`, and the usage is very much justified when specifying `std::function<int(int)>`, which declares a function type taking `int` as its only argument, and returning `int`.

However, the meaning of the above suddenly changes when the same notion is used in the context of `std::result_of<F(Args...)>` (note that I changed `R` to `F`, and removed the (space) between `F` and `(` to signify the difference - according to cppreference, the meaning of `F(Args...)` becomes a compile time `INVOKE` expression - I mean, I kind of understand that the main purpose of `std::result_of<F(Args...)>` is to use the notion of `INVOKE` to select the correct overload (if more than one overloads are present), and of course deduce the return type of such invocation (during compile time resolution) - effectively, this would roughly be similar to: `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))` - however, the notion of `F (Args...)` - comparing to the `std::function<R (Args...)>` case - would have been interpreted by the compiler as a function type taking `Args...` and returning the type `F`, where now `F` is the function type that we are trying to get the return type of!

Of course, with the help of `decltype` and `std::declval`, the implementation of `std::result_of` seems reasonable, but I read that boost somehow implemented `result_of` in C++98/03 where `decltype` and `std::declval` were not existing - I'm wondering how would that be possible (maybe with some very hack'ish tricks)?

So to re-iterate: is the notion of `R (Args...)` in the context of being a template argument *always* interpreted / deduced as a function type with a return type `R`, regardless if the enclosing template is `std::function<>` or `std::result_of<>`? while `std::result_of<>` somehow does some kind of reinterpretation of the "return type" `F`, and "returns" the actual return type as defined by `std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type`? Or `std::result_of<F(Args...)>` just interprets `F(Args...)` differently, so it knows it's a magical `INVOKE` expression?

Thanks for your upcoming clarification!

Comment: `std::result_of` is just abusing the function type syntax, and as [this note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of#Notes) says, it does not always work.

Answer (score 4):

`Z(A,B,C)` is just a type. It is a function type.

You can pass types to templates.  What the template does with a type is up to the template.

`std::function<X>` expects a function type.  It converts it into the signature of its `operator()`.

`std::result_of<X>` expects a function type.  If given `A(Ts...)`, it calculates the result of using `()` to call an object of type `A` with the arguments `Ts...`.

It was marked depricated in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) because function types do funny things sometimes (decay arguments, strip const, etc).  There is now `invoke_result<F, Ts...>` that behaves much like `result_of<F(Ts...)>` with a few corner case differences.

`result_of` was always an abuse of function type syntax.  But there is no deep magic here; templates do whatever they want with types passed in.

In [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) you can get limited "result_of" like functionality by pattern matching function pointer types and examining `&T::operator()`.  There is no way to get the entire capabilities you want in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) without decltype/declval, compiler extensions, or TR pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) headers.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a little deeper on how to possibly implement `result_of` without using `decltype`?

Comment: Also, you say `Z(A,B,C)` is a function type - to be more exact though, is it always interpreted by the compiler as a function type taking arguments of type `A`, `B`, `C` respectively, and returning type `Z`, or this notion could be interpreted differently by different templates? e.g. `std::function<>` would interpret `Z` as a return type, while `std::result_of<>` interprets `Z` as a "function type" itself?? Would be great if you could elaborate more on this.

Comment: @Dejavu it is **syntactically** a function taking `A, B, C` and returning `F`, but when those are template parameters, there **isn't** any function with that signature. It's a way of stuffing multiple template parameters from a partial specialisation into one template parameter of the primary template.

Comment: So, std::result_of has been kind of a hack from the beginning?

Comment: @dejavu I'd say "overly clever" rather than a hack.

Answer (score 1):

To implement it without `decltype`—well, a simple carcass oldschool implementation that covers few basic cases would probably be something like

```
template<class F> struct MemberRetVal;
template<class C,typename R> struct MemberRetVal<R (C::*)()> {
    using type = R;
};
template<class C,typename R> struct MemberRetVal<R (C::*)() const> {
    using type = R;
};
template<class C,typename R, typename A1> struct MemberRetVal<R (C::*)(A1)> {
    using type = R;
};
template<class C,typename R, typename A1> struct MemberRetVal<R (C::*)(A1) const> {
    using type = R;
};
// ...
// A few more member function arities
// ...

template<typename F> struct ResultOf;
template<typename F> struct ResultOf<F (*)()> {
    using type = typename MemberRetVal<&F::operator()>::type;
};
template<typename R> struct ResultOf<(R (*)())(*)()> {
    using type = R;
};
template<typename F, typename A1> struct ResultOf<F (*)(A1)> {
    using type = typename MemberRetVal<&F::operator()>::type;
};
template<typename R, typename A1> struct ResultOf<(R (*)(A1))(*)(A1)> {
    using type = R;
};
// and so forth
```

Somewhat more sophisticated dispatch is required for `operator()` case, but otherwise—this is the approximate way to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I was not able to get your code to compile with a simple sample, could you somehow make this a working example on Corliru? Thanks!